# How do I grant a cron job webcam access in Mac OSX Mojave?

Tags: cron, webcam, macos-mojave

In OSX Mojave, access to the camera is controlled by pop-up dialogs and the new System Preferences>>Security & Privacy>>Privacy>>camera panel, where apps can be granted (or denied) access to the camera.

I can grant "iterm2" access to the camera, which lets me run imagesnap from the commandline.

I use a cron job to capture a photograph of the cat bed every 60 seconds. This now fails, since upgrade to Mojave, because it does not have permission to access the camera. Is there any way I can give my cron job access? I don't get a pop-up dialog for a cron job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an Automator application wrapper also works.  Create the wrapper (run shell script), run in manually and grant it permission.  Then the cron job can call the Automator app.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works exactly as I wanted. My cron job now just does "open /path/to/automator.app" and automator app runs the original shell script.  The children will be thrilled to have the cat camera back.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked around this by using a wrapper script that indirects through Applescript to use iTerm, which does have permission, and have cron launch the wrapper.

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript << EOF 2>&1 | grep -v "window id"
tell application "iTerm"
  create window with default profile command "/path/to/capturescript"
end tell
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! This works (I had to change "iterm" to "iterm2") but brings the window up over the top of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - Mojave broke this further, and the Automator app broke.

I lost a lot of time fiddling with it, and then gave up. It seems the security of camera devices changed again. My time is expensive and raspberry pis are cheap; I connected the camera to a pi and now access it from cron with "ssh pi fswebcam - > output.jpg" which works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Automator on Mac.
2. Click `New Document`.
3. Choose Application.
4. In search bar search for `Run Shell Script` and add to application with click.
5. Add code for running your desired script (like you would run the script from shell).
6. On top right click `Run`.
7. Allow access to camera.

With installed cronjob you should be fine.